# dalli on heroku not caching

Tags: heroku, memcached, dalli

I want to enable action caching in my rails app on heroku.
In `development.rb` I set:

```
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

and see in logs

```
Started GET "..." for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-17 14:03:25 +0400
...
Write fragment ... 
OR
Read fragment ... (0.2ms)
```

->
To move to production I installed memcache add-on via `$heroku addons:add memcache` , installed new gem in Gemfile: `gem 'dalli'` and changed settings in `production.rb`:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store = :dalli_store #, ENV['MEMCACHE_SERVERS'], { :namespace => 'myapp', :expires_in => 1.day, :compress => true }
```

I have also tried to enable those two commented parameters, but anyway I don't see `Read/Write fragment ...` pieces in logs, I see that app gets authenticated, but cache is always missing

```
Started GET "..." for 195.178.108.38 at 2013-05-17 09:54:19 +0000
Dalli/SASL authenticating as myapp%40heroku.com
Dalli/SASL: Authenticated
cache: [GET ...] miss
```

Running `$heroku run console` I check that the cache is loading:

```
irb(main):001:0> Rails.cache.read('color')
Dalli/SASL authenticating as myapp%40heroku.com
Dalli/SASL: Authenticated
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> Rails.cache.write('color', 'red')
=> true
irb(main):003:0> Rails.cache.read('color')
=> "red"
```

Why action caching does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try using memcachier instead?

- remove memcahe add-on
- add memcachier add-on
- add "memcachier" gem just above "dalli" in your gem file
- it should "just work"

See here in the DevCenter: [Memcachier](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcachier)

Comment: I changed do Memcachier but nothing changed, but it seems that caching is working somehow. Anyway, thanks)